# Why does AA tree do the operation first skew and then split?

Tags: algorithm

Why does AA tree do the operation first skew and then split? What is the reason for this and why shouldn't the balancing functions be called on the contrary?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sub-tree:

```
     |
     v
  L<-T->R
 / \   / \
A   B C   D
```

If you apply skew first, and then split, you will get a legal tree.

```
      |
      v
      T
    /   \
   L     R 
  / \   / \
 A   B C   D
```

If you apply split first, then skew, you will get an illegal tree:

```
  |
  v
  L->T->R
 /  /  / \
A  B  C   D
```

Comment: What's striking about that change is that, in this case, the only change to the tree is that the level of T is raised. In immutable implementations this also avoids cloning two nodes to end up with an identical structure.